# Eclipse plugin: NoClassDefFoundError on org/eclipse/jdt/ui/JavaUI

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-jdt

I am creating a plugin which requires jdt.ui.JavaUI class. I included the jdt.ui plugin into the dependencies. This is my Manifest.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: PanelGenerator Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: PanelGeneratorPlugin; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.1.0
Bundle-Activator: panelgenerator.plugin.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.core,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui
Eclipse-LazyStart: true
```

and this is my build.properties:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
           META-INF/,\
           .,\
           icons/,\
           templates/
```

At compile time I do not get any compilation errors. If I debug the plugin using Eclipse (Debug as -> Eclipse Application) it works fine.

However when I export it, then install it copying it into the Eclipse plugins folder, the plugin does not work. As soon as the JavaUI class is used, nothing happens. The error log reports this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/ui/JavaUI
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: As suggested by Steve, could you give more details about how you "install" the plug-in (version of Eclipse used to develop the plug-in, version of Eclipse where the plug-in is installed, procedure used to export the plug-in, procedure used to install the plug-in, etc.).

The problem is likely occuring during the export/install phase because the plug-in works when you launch a new instance of Eclipse from your workspace.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the plugins in "Require-Bundle" is important! You should order them in a way such that the most basic ones come first.

I would suggest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: PanelGenerator Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: PanelGeneratorPlugin; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.1.0
Bundle-Activator: panelgenerator.plugin.Activator
Require-Bundle:  org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui
Eclipse-LazyStart: true
```

This is because eclipse loads the classes from the bundles in the order you provided. This may cause trouble if the order is not from "basic" to "non-basic". Try this, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is perhaps you are compiling against different versions than you are running against and there are non-binary-compatible changes.  You can see something similar in [eclipse bug 177476](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=177476) where this happened.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Eclipse are you trying this with? If you are using 3.4 (Ganymede) or 3.5 (Galileo), you can't just add new plugins to the plugins folder anymore. Try putting your plugin into the dropins folder instead (that is the intention of the dropins folder).

When your plugin is ready for a more permanent deployment, you can export it with P2 metadata and use the update manager to start it up.

If you're using an older version of Eclipse, the .log file will probably give you some details about the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you export plugin into a jar and just copy it over to **plugins** folder of your eclipse installation some dependencies will not work (including org.eclipse.jdt.ui). In fact, I believe that only packages inside org.eclipse.core will work properly if you distribute your plugin like this.

To actually install your plugin, you'll need to do one of the following:

1. Copy exported jar into **dropins** (not plugins) folder. Plugin will be installed next time you launch eclipse.
2. [Export and Install into the Running Host](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/export_wizards/export_features.htm)
3. Create a [feature](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/dependencies.htm) project, an [update site](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/dependencies.htm) and install your plugin via Install New Software options menu.